# 3D array to dict

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, 3d

I have an array with the following dimensions: (37, 121, 152). It's basically data over a geographic area (121 and 152 reprensent lat and lon), over 37 days. I would like to slice this array and store it into a dict with 37 keys.

I have no idea how to do this!

Comment: Could you edit your post with an example of your "3D array"?

Comment: And I assume for each key you want a lat x lon array? Also, why do you want to do this? If you want the data for some day, you could easily do `array[day]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be nice if you provided some sample code, it is easier for us to help you when there is code. We are working in the dark when there is no code.

This will create a dictionary with keys going from `0` to `36`.

```py
data_as_dict = {i:daily_data for i, daily_data in enumerate(data_as_array)}
```

Comment: This did exactly what I wanted to do! I have originally tried sub = np.array([sea_level_anomaly[a,:,:] for a in sea_level_anomaly]) but it wouldnt work... THANK YOU!

Comment: Looks equivalent to `dict(enumerate(data_as_array))`.

Answer (score 0):

A shorter method -

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.random((37, 121, 152))
dict(enumerate(arr))
```

We can also use a list comprehension -

```
{i:arr[i] for i in range(arr.shape[0])}
```

```
{0: array([[0.03587153, 0.00733576, 0.64817595, ..., 0.39584249, 0.78103435,
         0.51605369],
        [0.04765851, 0.51853953, 0.79437461, ..., 0.70687342, 0.99151754,
         0.2865933 ],
        [0.74195368, 0.9702369 , 0.01011108, ..., 0.06677645, 0.14794432,
         0.29168354],
        ...,
        [0.49454141, 0.49880604, 0.42167608, ..., 0.8111022 , 0.14036701,
         0.46243714],
        [0.82830127, 0.20608145, 0.24071568, ..., 0.97635812, 0.25148288,
         0.00285221],
        [0.16013346, 0.93088693, 0.76699837, ..., 0.14429432, 0.90871887,
         0.95358223]]),
 1: array([[0.31927665, 0.91979103, 0.9566047 , ..., 0.54962716, 0.32168082,
         0.16869125],
        [0.41893565, 0.47285146, 0.30876266, ..., 0.90161547, 0.33960162,
         0.54737103],
        [0.5908037 , 0.6471568 , 0.54996533, ..., 0.70905124, 0.13338396,
         0.57609446],
        ...,
        [0.98143214, 0.2392772 , 0.76211642, ..., 0.99660162, 0.73251072,
         0.9177692 ],
        [0.6912586 , 0.92501548, 0.65568306, ..., 0.65735284, 0.54854086,
         0.90320001],
        [0.86533528, 0.94201925, 0.91083406, ..., 0.60207038, 0.42076898,
         0.29382403]]),
```

---

Shapes for each value in key are -

```
{i:arr[i].shape for i in range(arr.shape[0])}
```

```
{0: (121, 152),
 1: (121, 152),
 2: (121, 152),
 3: (121, 152),
 4: (121, 152),
 5: (121, 152),
 6: (121, 152),
 7: (121, 152),
 8: (121, 152),
 9: (121, 152),
 10: (121, 152),
 11: (121, 152),
 12: (121, 152),
 13: (121, 152),
 14: (121, 152),
 15: (121, 152),
 16: (121, 152),
 17: (121, 152),
 18: (121, 152),
 19: (121, 152),
 20: (121, 152),
 21: (121, 152),
 22: (121, 152),
```

Comment: You're using a dict comprehension, not a list comprehension.

Comment: `dict([(i,j) for i,j in tups])` is exactly equivalent to `{i:j for i,j in tups}`, so technically its just the same thing, but yea it can be called as dict comprehension to be more specific. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you are using `list()`.  As an example, let's assume your list looks like

`your_array = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`

You could iterate through every `list` in your array, and take the first value as the `key`, and other values as `value`.

`your_dict = { i[0]:i[1:] for i in your_array }`

What I think you need is a **dict comprehension**, see that [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Like every said, example code is helpful!  What's your data look like?  It would give us great starting point.